# How do I make jQuery change the DOM on another webpage in my domain?

Tags: jquery

I can't figure out how to use jQuery on the webpage I'm on to make changes to another webpage's html in my 
domain. Suppose I want to change the following at mydomain.com/changedom.html:

```
<body>
<p id="changehere">This is the text I want to bold.</p>
</body>
```

and I'm in mydomain.com/index.html and I want to run jQuery to change the previous page as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">    
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('http://www.mydomain.com/changedom.html p#changehere').html(<b>This is the text I want to bold.</b>');
});
</script>
```

doesn't work for me. Help!

Comment: ummm.. do you have a database? do you know how websites work?

Comment: Are you asking how to use JavaScript so that when the browser **leaves the current page (A) and then goes to a different page (B)**, it will run some JS that will modify the DOM on B?

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript library that works in a browser. You cannot make changes to file that is not currently loaded in the browser

Comment: ajax + PHP - what you're trying with JS alone is impossible

Comment: Are you trying to include content from the external website on your own, then change the content within your own DOM? That's possible, but changing the other website is not.

Comment: do you know javascript/jquery? - even if your code made any sense `<b>This is the text I want to bold.</b>'` would need to be `'<b>This is the text I want to bold.</b>'` and that would delete the other text and **replace** it, which by the looks of it you dont want.

Comment: question translation "i got no clue what programming is, how do i make a for loop through a object of arrays in jquery? NOT a do/for a regular for/while with MyVAr vAr = '8' as (private) boolean `false`end if;,;"

Comment: Trivia: this question features what's known as the [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario yeah maybe but a x-y with no understanding of language, and whole set of languages, forget the actual issue at hand. damn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, or at least not like that.

The only way you could do that would be to have the content of your 'p#changewhere' coming from a database or some kind of storage.

Then on an event (such as dom ready but a click might be better) have an ajax post to a php (or other server side code) to change the value in the database for the 'p#changewhere' content.

There are other ways though, but I can't think of any that wouldnt require the  'p#changewhere' content being stored and not hard coded.

the web is stateless and all that jazz

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm being told the same thing over on forum.jquery.com. I probably need to learn PHP next since I work with WordPress a lot and that's what it's based on. Often, I want to make a change to another webpage whose html I can't edit directly - because its html is being output by PHP scripting.

I think I need to learn more about how PHP runs in WordPress's main theme file, called functions.php. Then I'd probably be able to issue $.ajax() to affect a change on another webpage I specify.

Thanks again for trying to help me!

Comment: No problem, its all part becoming a better developer. http://wp.tutsplus.com/ often has some good wordpress focused php stuff